# Simple dataframe query in R

Tags: r

In R, how can a dataframe be queried in a similar manner as an SQL table can be queried?

[image]

For instance, if I load the above .csv into RStudio, how can I create a function that lets me input a particular color, gender, and young/old in order to retrieve the exact value listed in the dataframe (e.g. function input is "blue, male, old" and output is "29")?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Rather than getting the community to write you code it is better to show what you have tried and has failed so we can help tweak your code. Also be sure to show a snippet of your data so we have something to work with.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data. You can use dput(data) and copy-paste it's output. People wanting to help you should be able to get your data loaded with a minimum of effort. Manually typing data is not minimum effort.

Comment: You might want to consider asking the higher-level question involved here.  OlivierDeMeulder's answer below is pretty much how you'd typically do this in R, but you can probably get better results by asking how to solve the problem that you're trying to solve with this.  Why do you want to query for a single element?

Comment: Wow thanks for your assistance, Heroka.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we go -- thanks again, Barranka and Olivier for the help.

```
subset(df, (Gender == 'Male' & Color == 'Blue'), select=c(Old))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could install a package to do this.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in subset function.

For example (if df is your dataframe):

```
subset(df, (Gender == 'Male' & Color == 'Blue'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Olivier -- your function outputs the full row of values rather than the single value. I tweaked your code below, however that also doesn't output a single value.

subset(df$Old, (Gender == 'Male' & Color == 'Blue'))

Answer (score 3):

> How can a dataframe be queried in a similar manner as an SQL table can be queried?

If you're familiar with SQL queries, R has your back covered! Take a look to the [`sqldf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html). You can manipulate data frames as if they were tables in a SQL database (more exactly, a SQLite database)

For your example (asuming your data is stored in a dataframe called `df`):

```
sqldf("select Old from df where Color = 'Blue' and Gender = 'Male'")
```

Of course, R has many ways to do things, so you may want to check [The Quick-R tutorial: Subsetting data](http://statmethods.net/management/subset.html).

Comment: Thank you, Barranka, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @SidneyCarton if it solves your issue accept it

Comment: Thanks to Heroka there, my reputation has just been halved (apparently for not having heard of "dput") which means I am no longer able to press "this answer is useful" for your useful answer. 

I suspect my ability to comment on my own questions will be removed next?

Comment: It's not too late to fix your question.

Comment: @SidneyCarton if you complain because people tell you the things that you can do better, then you have to ask yourself if it's worth helping you. [Please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com). (By the way, you have 4 down votes, and that means at least 4 people think that you can improve your question)

Comment: You misunderstand. My complaint was not related to the information provided (and only two responses were useful to that end), it was for the inability to mark your answer as useful, which you directly asked me to do.

Comment: @SidneyCarton accepting an answer is not dependent on your reputation.